# Set Alias in H2 Database during initialization

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, alias, h2

I have named queries from production code, which use Oracles `SUBSTR()` method. How can I make those calls work with H2s `SUBSTRING()`?

I am trying to test with H2. I created a copy of `hibernate.cfg.xml` and changed it so that it connects to the H2 database. `hibernate.cfg.xml` references some `*.hbm.xml` files, and some of them contain named queries, using Oracles `SUBSTR()`.

I've seen the documentation on `CREATE ALIAS` (http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_alias), but can not think of how to make it work early enough, so that the new command is even available during initialization of Hibernate.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:01 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:02 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle]
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:03 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:03 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Jun 24, 2019 4:01:05 PM org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
ERROR: HHH000177: Error in named query: findKindIdXXXXXXXXX
org.hibernate.QueryException: undefined alias: SUBSTR [SELECT
            xxx.yyyyy, SUBSTR(nmvz.eigKennzeichen, 2, 1)
        FROM
[...]
        WHERE
[...]
```

How can I define an alias early enough in hibernates initialization, so that this error message goes away?

Comment: Running tests on one database for code intended to be executed on a different database is rife with these sorts of problems. The only guaranteed solution is to use an Oracle database for your tests. Oracle XE is free, so why not use it?

Comment: No, in this case, there are very few proprietary commands, plus we are trying to get rid of them.